# Gparted won't re-partition under 16.04.4

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

Long description because it's complicated.

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04.4 LTS with xfce on my primary tower machine.

On a recent re-boot, one of my hard drives was no longer visible under File System.  The drive had important, but not critical information, and I had a backup of the drive.

I attempted to re-partition the drive with gparted - no joy - the error message is "/dev/sda: unrecognised disk label".  I also tried working the drive with gnome-disks and wiping the drive with mkusb -- still not able to create a partition.

I removed the drive from the tower, inserted it into my BlacX external drive device.  Still wasn't able to create a partition.  This eliminated the internal MB SATA port as the problem.

As a test, I attached the BlacX to my laptop which is running Kubuntu 16.04.1 -- I was able to partition the hard drive.  The drive is now operating just fine, back on the main tower machine, still sitting in the BlacX housing.  I will be installing the hard drive back into the tower case, soon.

For some reason, seemingly, 16.04.4 won't re-partition a hard drive, while 16.04.1 has no problem doing so.

Thanks for any help on this issue.

Jim

Answer (score 0):

The error message "*/dev/sda: unrecognised disk label*" indicates that there was no partition table recognized on the drive.  Perhaps the important sectors containing the partition table were somehow overwritten.  Another possibility is that the drive did not contain a partition table and was perhaps entirely formatted with a file system.

You might wish to check the health of the drive with a program such as **gsmartcontrol** to see if the drive is reporting excessive errors.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with the hard drive.  I was able to re-partition the drive using my laptop running 16.04.1 -- It would appear that something has changed between .1 and .4 such that re-partitioning doesn't work.  GJim

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved.

The problem isn't with Kubuntu.  The MB SATA port that was being used for the hard-drive is bad - actually 2 SATA ports are bad.  Ports are numbered 0-5.  Hard-drive was originally on port 4, switching to port 5 still had the same problem.  Using port 3, all is well with the drive.

Will have to order/install a new MotherBoard, near future.

Jim